# Java data structure Stack using Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures

I was trying to implement Stack (push) using LinkedList in Java then I realized that I had a big problem, even though I was attaching new nodes they were not there while traversing.

I realized that I was using a Node object previously defined again and again so the data was being re-written. Like the code following:

```
package LLAPPLICATION;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Node {
    Node next;
    int data;
}

public class Stack {
    Node first;

    void push(Node node) {
        if (first == null) {
            first = node;
            first.next = null;

        } else if (first.next == null) {
            first.next = node;
            node.next = null;
        } else {
            Node temp = new Node();
            temp = first;
            while (temp.next != null) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp.next = node;
            node.next = null;
        }
    }                

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack stk = new Stack();
        Node tmp = new Node();
        char cho;
        do {
        System.out.print("Enter the element to insert ::");
                        /* This is the part where it got tricky.If I use tmp by declaring it at the top it just wont happen.I think its because of garbage collection i.e. every iteration causes new instance i.e tmp to be created and hence preventing it from being overwritten*/
                        tmp.data = inp.nextInt();
                        stk.push(tmp);
                        System.out.print("Do you want to PUSH again..(Y/N):");
                        cho = inp.next().charAt(0);
                    } while (cho == 'Y' || cho == 'y');

      }
}
```

Then I did it like this and it worked. Now I am really confused, I think it is because of Garbage collection but not sure.

```
package LLAPPLICATION;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Node {
    Node next;
    int data;
}

public class Stack {

    Node first;

    void push(Node node) {
        if (first == null) {
            first = node;
            first.next = null;

        } else if (first.next == null) {
            first.next = node;
            node.next = null;
        } else {
            Node temp = new Node();
            temp = first;
            while (temp.next != null) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp.next = node;
            node.next = null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack stk = new Stack();
        char cho;

                    do {
        /*If I declare a tmp inside of the loop it does*/
                        Node tmp = new Node();
                        System.out.print("Enter the element to insert ::");
                        tmp.data = inp.nextInt();
                        stk.push(tmp);
                        System.out.print("Do you want to PUSH again..(Y/N):");
                        cho = inp.next().charAt(0);
                  } while (cho == 'Y' || cho == 'y');
        }
}
```

Comment: @efekctive I have posted both version I hope it does the work

Comment: There isn't really a question in your question. And your code is not very minimal in a way that makes it easy to help.

Comment: @E_net4 I'm sorry for the inconvenience, this is my first time asking so I'm was not sure how to ask. Thank you !Now I know how to ask a question properly and next time I ask a question I will follow the standard so that it's easy for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You have pretty much everything wrong. It is an stack. You care about last and previous. Push only needs to make this.last->node.previous and node becomes last. Pop only needs to do the opposite.

Traversal is not needed.

```
void push(Node node){
    if (this.last != null)
        node.previous = this.last;
    this.last = node;
    size++
}

Node pop(){
   if (this.last == null){
   // Exception/etc
   }
   Node n = this.last;
   this.last = n.previous;
   size--
   return node;
}
```